# piping in c, 2 forks talk to main

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe

Ok so short story is:
I have a program that need to do X and it does 0.25X. I use 2 forks and 4 pipes, and I dont know how to debug this. (using eclipse c/c++ in linux env).

Long story:
I have a program that need to calculate gcd (Greatest common divisor) from a text file containing pairs of ints. This program has a father (main) and 2 childerns (forks) that need to talk to the father through pipes. (2 pipes for each childern.)
When I complie and run the program in ubuntu, I get no error but the proram doesnt complete its tasks. I have no idea where/why it breaks. How can I debug this? Im coding in eclipse c/c++ and debugger can't handle the forks.. When I debug it is reading all numbers from file (doesnt calculate gcd) but when I run in ubuntu terminal it only reads first line and breaks. here is the full code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
if (argc != 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "‫‪usage: %s <FILE NAME>\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int pfd_child1_r[2], pfd_child1_w[2], pfd_child2_r[2], pfd_child2_w[2];
if (pipe(pfd_child1_r) == -1 || pipe(pfd_child1_w) == -1
        || pipe(pfd_child2_r) == -1 || pipe(pfd_child2_w) == -1) {
    perror("cannot pipe()");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

createChilds(pfd_child1_r, pfd_child1_w, pfd_child2_r, pfd_child2_w);

FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("fopen(): ");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

char line[100];
char *token;
int numbers[2], num, line_count = 1, counter = 0, result = 0;

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
    token = strtok(line, " ");
    while (token != NULL) {
        num = atoi(token);
        if (num < 1 || counter == 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "‫‪illegal‬‬ ‫‪input‬‬ at line %d\n",
                    line_count);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        numbers[counter] = num;
        counter++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    counter = 0;
    if (line_count % 2 == 0) { // use first child
        write(pfd_child1_w[1], &numbers[0], sizeof(int));
        write(pfd_child1_w[1], &numbers[1], sizeof(int));
    } else { // use second child
        write(pfd_child2_w[1], &numbers[0], sizeof(int));
        write(pfd_child2_w[1], &numbers[1], sizeof(int));
    }

    if (line_count > 1) { // after first run alternate to get result
        if (line_count % 2 == 0) { // read from second child
            read(pfd_child2_r[0], &result, sizeof(int));
            printf("%d %d\t\tgcd: %d\n", numbers[0], numbers[1], result);
        } else { // read from first child
            read(pfd_child1_r[0], &result, sizeof(int));
            printf("%d %d\t\tgcd: %d\n", numbers[0], numbers[1], result);
        }
    }

    line_count++;
}

fclose(fp);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void createChilds(int pfd_child1_r[2], int pfd_child1_w[2], int pfd_child2_r[2],

    int pfd_child2_w[2]) {

switch (fork()) {
case -1:
    perror("cannot fork()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

case 0: /* First child: */
    if (close(pfd_child1_r[0]) == -1) { /* Read end is unused */
        perror("cannot close()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (close(pfd_child1_w[1]) == -1) { /* Write end is unused */
        perror("cannot close()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Duplicate stdout on write end of pipe; close duplicated descriptor */

    if (pfd_child1_w[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) { /* Defensive check */
        if (dup2(pfd_child1_r[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
            perror("cannot dup2()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (close(pfd_child1_r[1]) == -1) {
            perror("cannot close()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Duplicate stdin on read end of pipe; close duplicated descriptor */

    if (pfd_child1_w[1] != STDIN_FILENO) { /* Defensive check */
        if (dup2(pfd_child1_w[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
            perror("cannot dup2()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (close(pfd_child1_w[0]) == -1) {
            perror("cannot close()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    execlp("./v1_child", "./v1_child", NULL); /* Writes to pipe */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

default: /* Parent go to next child */
    break;
}

switch (fork()) {
case -1:
    perror("cannot fork()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

case 0: /* Second child: exec 'wc' to read from pipe */
    if (close(pfd_child2_r[0]) == -1) { /* Read end is unused */
        perror("cannot close()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (close(pfd_child2_w[1]) == -1) { /* Write end is unused */
        perror("cannot close()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Duplicate stdout on write end of pipe; close duplicated descriptor */

    if (pfd_child2_w[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) { /* Defensive check */
        if (dup2(pfd_child2_r[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
            perror("cannot dup2()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (close(pfd_child2_r[1]) == -1) {
            perror("cannot close()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Duplicate stdin on read end of pipe; close duplicated descriptor */

    if (pfd_child2_w[1] != STDIN_FILENO) { /* Defensive check */
        if (dup2(pfd_child2_w[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
            perror("cannot dup2()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (close(pfd_child2_w[0]) == -1) {
            perror("cannot close()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    execlp("./v1_child", "./v1_child", NULL); /* Writes to pipe */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

default: /* Parent falls through */
    break;
}

/* Parent closes unused file descriptors for pipe */

if (close(pfd_child1_r[1]) == -1 || close(pfd_child1_w[0]) == -1
        || close(pfd_child2_r[1]) == -1 || close(pfd_child2_w[0]) == -1) {
    perror("cannot close()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

the second file is the gcd file, i still have not finish it and the loop the should keep geting the numbers is not present. but i just want to get the first line working properly then i will fix the rest.

```
int gcd(int n1, int n2) {
    if (n2 == 0)
        return n1;
    return gcd(n2, n1 % n2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int n1, n2, result;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &n1,&n2) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error reading numbers in child\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (n1 > n2)
        result = gcd(n1, n2);
    else
        result = gcd(n2,n1);
    printf("%d", result);
}
```

Comment: If a user requests `--help`, it is not an error and the usage message should not be written to stderr.   (How often does one do `cmd --help | less`?).

Comment: The defensive checks are checking wrong descriptors. They shouldn’t harm, though, as long as both stdin and stdout exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to Debug**

An easy way to debug is always to add `fprintf(stderr, "...")` statements to the child program. Then you can run the program and also see what the child processes are doing.

**Transfer Values**

Since you redirect stdin and stdout and use sscanf/printf in the v1_child program which calculates gcd, I assume you want to transfer the values as strings.

An easy way could be to use fprintf to write ints as formatted strings. You could use fdopen to associate a stream to an existing pipe file descriptor.

Accordingly, you must convert numbers from and to strings.

**Variable Length Data and Buffered I/O**

If you use strings to transfer values, each pair of values has a variable length. Typically, a newline character is used in a C program to signal a complete input record.

Another reason for reading/writing a whole line is that read/write calls can also transfer only a partial number of bytes. You must therefore know when an input record is completed. An alternative would be to have a binary format, which would automatically represent a format with fixed lengths.

By using streams you work with buffered I/O, with fflush you can ensure that all buffered data is written through the underlying write function of the stream.

**Functions**

One could divide the features into several functions to make the flow a little easier to understand.

**Possible Improvements**

This should perhaps already be a start.

Another possible improvement could be the use of strtol instead of atoi, since atoi does not perform error checking. Similar sscanf does not report conversion errors (e.g. non-numeric characters at the end of the line), at least we look at the number of assigned input items.

There are presumably still possibilities to improve the readability of the code.

With waitpid the exit status code of the child could be checked in the parent.

**Program**

Your code, slightly modified in the points mentioned above, could then look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void create_pipe(int *);
void close_fd(int);
int child(const int *, const int *);
int read_input_line(FILE *fp, char *line, int max, int *numbers, int line_count);
void write_to_child(FILE *fp, const int *numbers);
int read_from_child(FILE *fp);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "‫‪usage: %s <FILE NAME>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int pfd_child1_r[2];
    int pfd_child1_w[2];
    int pfd_child2_r[2];
    int pfd_child2_w[2];

    create_pipe(pfd_child1_r);
    create_pipe(pfd_child1_w);
    create_pipe(pfd_child2_r);
    create_pipe(pfd_child2_w);

    pid_t pid1 = fork();

    if (pid1 == 0) { //child 1
        close_fd(pfd_child2_r[0]);
        close_fd(pfd_child2_r[1]);
        close_fd(pfd_child2_w[0]);
        close_fd(pfd_child2_w[1]);
        return child(pfd_child1_r, pfd_child1_w);
    } else if (pid1 > 0) {
        close_fd(pfd_child1_r[1]);
        close_fd(pfd_child1_w[0]);

        pid_t pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0) { //child 2
            close_fd(pfd_child1_r[0]);
            close_fd(pfd_child1_w[1]);
            return child(pfd_child2_r, pfd_child2_w);
        } else if (pid2 > 0) {
            close_fd(pfd_child2_r[1]);
            close_fd(pfd_child2_w[0]);

            FILE *fp_child1_w = fdopen(pfd_child1_w[1], "w");
            FILE *fp_child2_w = fdopen(pfd_child2_w[1], "w");
            FILE *fp_child1_r = fdopen(pfd_child1_r[0], "r");
            FILE *fp_child2_r = fdopen(pfd_child2_r[0], "r");

            if (!fp_child1_w || !fp_child2_w || !fp_child1_r || !fp_child2_r) {
                perror("fdopen() failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            if (fp == NULL) {
                perror("fopen(): ");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            char line[100];
            int numbers[2], line_count = 0;
            while (read_input_line(fp, line, sizeof(line), numbers, line_count) == 2) {
                if (line_count % 2 == 0) {
                    write_to_child(fp_child1_w, numbers);
                } else {
                    write_to_child(fp_child2_w, numbers);
                }

                if (line_count % 2 == 0) {
                    int result = read_from_child(fp_child1_r);
                    printf("%d %d\t\tgcd: %d\n", numbers[0], numbers[1], result);
                } else {
                    int result = read_from_child(fp_child2_r);
                    printf("%d %d\t\tgcd: %d\n", numbers[0], numbers[1], result);
                }
                line_count++;
            }

            //fclose closes also associated file descriptor
            fclose(fp_child1_w);
            fclose(fp_child2_w);
            fclose(fp_child1_r);
            fclose(fp_child2_r);

            fclose(fp);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        } else {
            perror("second fork failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } else {
        perror("first fork failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}


int read_input_line(FILE *fp, char *line, int max, int *numbers, int line_count) {
    char *token;
    int num, counter = 0;

    line[0] = '\0';
    if (fgets(line, max, fp) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(line, " ");
        while (token != NULL) {
            num = atoi(token);
            if (num < 1 || counter == 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "‫‪illegal‬‬ ‫‪input‬‬ at line %d\n", line_count + 1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            numbers[counter] = num;
            counter++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

int read_from_child(FILE *fp) {
    char buf[128];
    int result = -1;
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &result) == 1)
            return result;
    }
    return -1;
}

void write_to_child(FILE *fp, const int *numbers) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n", numbers[0], numbers[1]);
    fflush(fp);
}

int child(const int *pfd_child_r, const int *pfd_child_w) {
    dup2(pfd_child_r[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(pfd_child_w[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close_fd(pfd_child_r[0]);
    close_fd(pfd_child_r[1]);
    close_fd(pfd_child_w[0]);
    close_fd(pfd_child_w[1]);
    execlp("./v1_child", "./v1_child", NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "execution of v1_child failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void create_pipe(int *fd) {
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("cannot pipe()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void close_fd(int fd) {
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        perror("cannot close()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

The corresponding v1_child.c could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int gcd(int n1, int n2) {
    if (n2 == 0)
        return n1;
    return gcd(n2, n1 % n2);
}

int main(void) {

    int n1, n2, result;
    char buf[128];
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d %d", &n1, &n2) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error reading numbers in child\n");
            return -1;
        }
        if (n1 > n2)
            result = gcd(n1, n2);
        else
            result = gcd(n2, n1);
        printf("%d\n", result);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Test**

With the input of

```
5 25
49 14
64 462
1155 84
```

the output would be

```
5 25        gcd: 5
49 14       gcd: 7
64 462      gcd: 2
1155 84     gcd: 21
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! I really appriciate taking the time for helping me.. I will go line by line to make sure I understand evreything but this is amazing, thank you again.

Comment: Hey friend, I have some follow-ups I would appriciate adressing: 1. Why the use of fflush is a MUST? I thought if you print newline ("\n") it would automatically send the input and clean the buffer? 2. At read_line function you insert  line[0] = '\0'. Why is that? I can't see a difference if I remove this line of code. 3. Last thing is.. What is I can't use fdopen, and want to use write() and read() system calls? I can't add my code in this comment but can you at least point to me the differences between the versions? THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: 1) Streams are typically only line buffered if they refer to an interactive terminal session. In our case the stream is associated with a pipe therefore it is fully buffered and we need to flush the buffer.

2) Since we do not evaluate the line on the caller side, if we return counter!=2, we would not have to do it. But if we want to use line later on the caller side, e.g. for debugging output , we would have to consider that fgets will not set its buffer if end-of-file is detected.

Comment: 3) It is certainly possible to use only read and write. For example, you could use sprintf to output the numbers formatted into a string and then send the string with write. In the same way, when reading a chunk of bytes, you could check if `\n' is included. You would also have to handle the case of partial reads. Taking this into account, streams with fprintf and fgets are just slightly more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You write binary values to the pipes, but try to read text representation. So either use a variation of `printf` (like `dprintf`) in the parent, or (better) use `read` (and `write`) in the child.